# How to make a Ø25cm notch/groove/slot, 20mm thick, 10cm deep, in the ground?

Tags: tools, drill, hand-tools, soil

Strange need isn't it? It is to seal no bottom pots in the soil, like in the following photo but without the bottoms:

[image]

[image]

It is a circular notch or a groove or a slot, not a hole.

I have imagined this solution, with no soldering:

Main parts:

- 1x 1m steel rod with rectangular section 100mm x 40mm 3mm thick (6kg)
- 2x steel rod with circular section Ø25mm, 250mm long (2x 1kg)
- 1x drill Ø30mm, 500mm long (3kg)
- 2x cables 1m long, resistance 100kg
- 2x handles
- M5 headless screws with conic ends, 4mm long (rod thickness + 1mm)

Mounting:

- Grind the 2x Ø25mm rods in the bottom 100mm in V-shape to help cut the soil (20mm at thickest)
- Drill the main road in the 100mm axis at its center Ø30mm, then at 12.5mm from its center in the same axis Ø25mm. They will receive respectively the drill and the circular roads
- Drill laterally and tap for small screws in order to maintain solidly the roads and the drill
- Drill the main rod at its extremity to mount the cables and set the handles at their end

[image]

Usage:

- Drive in the drill in the soil until the lateral roads come into contact. One can turn on itself to help since it is a drill
- Two people turn around the hole pulling on the handles with one hand. The central drill makes the lateral rods sink into the soil

Specs:

- The tool shall not exceed say 15kg to be easily handled by two people
- The tool shall enable to make a Ø25cm notch, 20mm thick, 10cm deep in less than 1 minute, so not too light
- The tool shall be robust to perform thousands of operations
- Easy and efficient operation
- Preferably with no soldering
- Not motorized tool
- Clay soil not easy to dig with a shovel
- No stones in the ground

Questions:

- Do you have a better solution?
- For this solution, what would be the best dimensioning (sections, lever arms, length) taking into account materials resistance, to best fulfil the specs?

Comment: Seems like you want an anti-thief solution?  If so the material of the pot needs to be as strong or stronger than what you use to hold it.  If you explain the why better, might get better ideas.  I would just dig a hole and put the pot/s in the hole, should keep them in place.  Even with the pots on top, the dirt in them should be enough, if not a simple stake driven down into the dirt and tie the pot to it.

Comment: Dig hole, insert pot, put dirt back in pot. Nobody gets injured by whirling unguarded steel bits. "But I want it **fast**" - great, they make posthole diggers that mount on tractors. But for 10 cm deep, a shovel will do in "less than a minute" unless the soil is absurdly hard. And two people can dig two holes at once. You are re-creating one of the most dangerous tools you can put in a drill press (a fly cutter) on a large scale and proposing that it should be operated by a hand-held drill. Someone *will* get hurt.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this is not an electrical tool but a small ["donkey mill"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkWNp.jpg) but for core-drilling rather than grinding. How is it going to be persuaded to stay upright whist two people walk round in circles? How are you going to apply sufficient vertical force to make it actually drill? What provision is there to push out the drill core? What if you hit a rock? I'd just get a [drain spade](https://www.toolstation.com/roughneck-fibreglass-handle-drain-spade/p51294) or [rabbiting spade](https://www.toolstation.com/bulldog-rabbiting-spade/p68551)

Comment: @crip659 it is not anti-thief, but anti-wind, so I need to anchor them a little in the ground

Comment: Dirt in them and one or two stakes driven into the ground and tie with cord or wire, will prevent any wind tip overs/blowing away, except maybe an  tornado.  If no bottom in the pot, can put stakes inside the pot so they don't show.

Comment: @Ecnerwal it is not motorized and soil is a clay one, not easy to dig. No tractor.

Comment: @Tetsujin 1) "upright": that's the role of the central drill. 2) "sufficient vertical force" : central drill that screws in the soil plus weight of the tool. 3) "push out" : turn opposite until lift is possible. 4) No rocks.

Comment: @crip659 3 stakes per pot is a lot of stakes to prepare (600). At the end of the season, they have to be unset, cleaned and stored. I am afraid the overall workload is bigger.

Comment: manual post hole digger, it's kind of like  dirt pliers.

Comment: 100kg cables are going to snap if someone tugs on them, you should really use something stronger than parachute cord.

Comment: This is looking like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, what is it that you're actually trying to accomplish?  You're looking to create a hole in the ground, but you want it to be reasonably precise? What do you mean by "make a _notch_ in the ground"? Usually a "notch" is a piece cut out of a corner or edge, so your choice of words is confusing. You're looking for a hole 25cm across and 10cm deep, what does 20mm "thick" mean? Are you looking to insert the things in the 1st picture into the ground?

Comment: @Freeman: a circular groove of 20mm thickness, Ø25cm, not a hole. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how having the central auger actually helps usage, just drive a metal post into the ground, then have a  sleeve on the tool that so that it rotates on post.  with the central post there is no need for a symmetrical design, just have one lever arm and a single plough blade.

your kit will now need to include a post driver and a post extractor

Comment: symmetricity makes it more stable

Comment: it only needs to be sufficiently stable. the post will do that.